# MVC.NET Get full view path in ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, path, actionfilterattribute

How can I get the full view path of the current rendered view in ActionFilterAttribute?
I can not find a solutions.

I just want to do some stuff in OnActionExecuted (custom validation ect.) and if the validation fails, I want to display the calling site with the validation error(s) - it seemed simple to me, but it is not, because I cannot find the full path of the latest rendered view ...

So far it workds on OnActionExecuted with this code for a hard-coded view.

```
filterContext.Result = new ViewResult() {
      ViewName = "~/Views/Login/Index.cshtml", // This is the path of the view with the calling form
      ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(filterContext.Controller.ViewData) {
        Model = ApplicationFiler.GetViewModel(filterContext)
      }
    };
```

So far I thought I could get the full path of the latest rendered view in the context, but I can't. How can I get the full path that really was rendered?

Then I thought, maybe I can get the information after the execution of the action in OnActionExecuted to save the path temporary and use it later. 
But still I am not able to find the full path (I need the full path of the view which was returned on the last Action execution without any errors).

Do I really have to temporary save the full path on every action that was executed?

Comment: Its not clear why you want that - you just return the view in the method if `ModelState` is invalid to display validation errors.

Comment: I do not want to call the action method and do the check of the  ModelState in every action method. I want to check it globally in the action filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access View path from action filter in the following way:

```
public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    ViewResult viewResult = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
    RazorView view = viewResult?.View as RazorView;
    string viewPath = view?.ViewPath;

    // ...
}
```

You should be ready that `ViewResult` is not the only possible `ActionResult` returned by controller. Controller could return other action results (e.g. `HttpNotFoundResult` or `JsonResult`). In this case obviously no view could be accessed in action filter. Construct `filterContext.Result as ViewResult` will return `null`.